# Update variable in bash function and use it in prompt (PS1)

Tags: bash, shell, scripting, sh

What I want to do is to call a function in `PS1` to update a variable inside the function. Then I like to use that variable to add another line to PS1. Like bellow:

```
my_func(){
   var="_RED_"
   echo "hello in red"
}
PS1="\[\033]0;\w\007\]"
PS1+='$(my_func)'
if [ $var = "_RED_" ]; then               # here I want to use that var
   PS1+="\[$(tput setaf 124)\] red"
fi
```

The reason for doing this is to bring non-printable characters `\[` and `\]` out of the function to prevent from overlapping long lines that is caused by `\[ \]`

Comment: hm, I could imagine that the function will only be called when PS1 is being printed, so at that time your init script has long finished. But I don't fully understand why you would use it - in the example $var will _always_ be "\_RED\_" and the comparison always be false (as you compare with "\_RED" without trailing underscore)

Comment: It was a typo. Thanks

Comment: Why are you trying to call the function from within PS1, rather than using the `PROMPT_COMMAND` hook that exists for the purpose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What I want to do is to call a function in PS1 to update a variable inside the function. Then I like to use that variable to add another line to PS1.

From your sample code, I suppose you mean that you want to perform a command expansion involving a shell function in the process of assigning a value to `PS1`.  *[update:] Since you've tagged the question [bash], we'll presume that you are specifically interested in the behavior of GNU Bash, which differs from that of a fully-conforming POSIX shell in this area.*  <s>It is important in that case to recognize that that the command expansion will be performed *once*, at the time the value of `PS1` is set / modified, not each time `PS1` is displayed.  Your wording and specific syntax make me suspect that you have a different expectation.</s>

Consider this part of your code:

> ```
> PS1="\[\033]0;\w\007\]"
> PS1+='$(my_func)'
> ```

Because it appears in single quotes, the `$(my_func)` is not subject to command expansion or any other expansion at the time that it is appended to your prompt string.  <s>Although the single quotes are removed before the value is appended to `PS1`, that does not mean it will be subject to expansion later.</s>  *Unlike a fully-conforming POSIX shell, however, Bash will perform command substitution on the prompt string before printing it.*

Now, because the function body is a curly-braced compound command, if it is executed then it will indeed set the value of `var` in the current shell, and that effect will be visible after the function returns.  However,

1. *(update, per @CharlesDuffy:) the command in a command substitution is run in a subshell.  Although a variable update in that subshell would persist past the function return, its scope is limited to the subshell, which exits almost immediately thereafter.*
2. <s>Again, nothing in the code you presented results in your function ever being called, and</s>
3. even if it were called, and it did set `var` in the current shell, you test for a value of `$var` different from the one your function would set.

In contrast, consider this other fragment of your code:

> ```
> PS1+="\[$(tput setaf 124)\] red"
> ```

Because the whole string is double-quoted in this case, the contents are unequivocally subject to command expansion.  If this were executed, the `$(tput setaf 124)` would be replaced with the output from running `tput setaf 124`.  That would happen at the time that `PS1`'s value is modified, not every time its value is displayed.

Although you can generate a prompt that contains ANSI escape sequences, you cannot do it quite the way you're trying to do.  Inasmuch as your specific needs are unclear, I hesitate to suggest a particular alternative.

Comment: Thanks for explanation. I can not mark it as answer as it did not give a solution to my question.

Comment: @HamidBazargani, it is up to you to determine what answer, if any, to accept.  However, if based on my answer you acknowledge that there is no solution to your problem as you have presented it, then I *have* answered your *question*, and with the only answer possible.

Comment: You are right. I solved my issue by approaching it differently.

Comment: This answer seems a bit deficient -- it's covering the difference in execution time between the function assigning a value to PS1 and the evaluation of the contents of PS1, yes, but it's not at all covering the difference between the subshell running `my_func` and the outer shell which would be looking for the change in the resulting global variable.

Comment: Ahh, but the _way_ the OP is executing it is via command substitution. That command substitution creates a subshell is, I'd argue, a rather important point. (So yes, you're pointing out that it changes "the current shell", and that's accurate insofar as it goes, but whether "the current shell" is what the OP may expect it to be...)

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, yes, I see your point.  I wasn't quick enough at deleting my comment.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, I hope you'll agree that my answer is better now.  On the other hand, I hope you'll also recognize that you're arguing a hypothetical.  The immediate problem is not which shell the function runs in, but the fact that it never runs at all, on account of the single quotes around what otherwise could be a command substitution.

Comment: @JohnBollinger, PS1 *does* evaluate command substitutions at render time. This is thus by no means hypothetical. You can trivially test this yourself: `PS1='$(pwd):'` does in fact render the current working time. It's true that it's running too late to impact the other append (happening at assignment time), but it does in fact run, and this would be relevant if the OP were trying to use, say, a second command substitution leveraging a variable set by the first.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, this is apparently a subtle point, so thanks for bringing it out.  GNU Bash does perform command substitution on the prompt string, but a fully-conforming POSIX shell performs only parameter substitution and expansion of `!` to a history number.  We are talking specifically about Bash, however, so you're right.

Answer (score 3):

You can absolutely update global variables inside a shell function -- **all** assignments inside functions modify global variables unless `local` or `declare` variables were used to create a new scope.

The problem here, however, is that you aren't running your function in the same shell process as the code that later tries to read `var` (though whether it is in fact "later" or not is a separate issue)! When you use command substitution -- the `$()` in `$(my_func)` -- you're creating a new forked-off subprocess to run that function. When that subprocess exits, all changes to variable values it's made are lost with it.

However, you can work around that by *not* using command substitution at all. Consider the below, which uses the `PROMPT_COMMAND` hook to assign `PS1`:

```
# code to run before each time a prompt is printed
PROMPT_COMMAND='build_ps1_func'

# rewrite your function to write to a named variable, not stdout
my_func(){
   local outvar=$1; shift # named variable to write stdout to
   var="_RED_"            # hardcoded global to update, per question
   printf -v "$outvar" '%s' "hello in red"
}

build_ps1_func() {
  local your_str    # define your_str as a local variable
  my_func your_str  # call my_func, telling it to write output to your_str

  PS1="\[\033]0;\w\007\]"
  PS1+="$your_str"
  if [ $var = "_RED_" ]; then        # using that variable here
    PS1+="\[$(tput setaf 124)\] red"
  fi
}
```